# Is there a better way to aggregate data from SharePoint lists than a SQL Report?

Tags: 2013, 2010, report-viewer

I have a SP2010 site that is using a SQL Report (and Report Viewer Web Part) to aggregate and display data from multiple SharePoint lists, all on that same site.  The report does not connect to any external database source, only the SharePoint lists.

I am supposed to move the site to SP2013, which, for the lists themselves, is straightforward enough.

However there has also been a request for me to see if I can somehow improve on the report.  It does seem to be a bit slow and clunky.

So my question is - in SP2013, is there a better way to aggregate and display data from multiple SharePoint lists (considering no external data source is involved)?

Comment: Aggregate with the REST API and use your favorite client side charting tool? And I hope you are using SSRS and not directly querying your SP database tables.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there was an OOB webpart / webparts that would do it without a lot of custom coding.  We are not using SSRS as far as I know, but the connection type in the report data source is "Microsoft SharePoint List", and the connection string is the URL of the site, so I think it is connecting directly to the site / lists somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a custom result source (http://www.sharepoint24x7.com/2014/10/01/article-customizing-sharepoint-2013-results-using-result-sources/), and if needed a custom display template (http://www.eliostruyf.com/?s=display+templates).

This is something that's greatly improved over 2010 and something you could use more often as well.

- Plus: Very fast to render, as it doesn't have to query all the lists all
  the time. It just queries the search db
- Plus: Could be a no-code solution if you don't need a display template
- Plus: If you don't want to use a display template you can always query the rest endpoint of search
- Negative: You would have to wait for items to be indexed before they show up.